# How to create multiple tables row from an Array in meteor

Tags: javascript, arrays, templates, meteor, handlebars.js

Hi there I was wondering how to create multiple tables rows from an array with  a template helper? Currently I am getting all the images in my array returned in the same row. Ideally I want each image to have its own row in the table. How would I approach this?

```
   <template name="stop">  
      <tr>
        {{#each thumb}} 
        <td class="image"><img src="{{this}}"></td>{{/each}}
        <td>

      </td>
      </tr>
    </template>
```

Here is my template helper.

```
      Template.stop.helpers({

        'thumb': function(data){

        return Chartdata.findOne().data;

        },
        'snippet': function(){
            return x[1]
        }
    });
```

Chartdata.findOne().data; is equal to an array of image urls.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just move your array iteration (`{{#each}}`) up to the row level ?

```
<template name="stop">
  {{#each thumb}}
    <tr> 
      <td class="image">
        <img src="{{this}}">
      </td>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

This way, each item in the array will be rendered as a new row (`<tr>`).

Comment: Ah yes I see what you mean but what if I had two template helpers that returned different information in the same table row. How would I be able to  output and iterate through them both without their {{#each}} statements interfering with each other.